# Python Pandas interpolation: redistribute value forwards over missing date range

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, interpolation, series

I have time trend data on facility traffic (admissions to and releases from a facility over time), with gaps. Because of the structure of this data, when a gap appears, the "releases" one day prior to the gap are artificially high (accounting for all unseen individuals released over the period of the gap), and the "admissions" one day after the gap are artificially high (for the same reason: any individual who was admitted during the gap and remains in the facility will appear as an "admission" on this date).

Here is a sample Pandas series involving such a data gap (with zeroes implying missing data on 2020-01-04 through 2020-01-07):

```
date(index)    releases    admissions
2020-01-01     15          23
2020-01-02     8           20
2020-01-03     50          14
2020-01-04     0           0
2020-01-05     0           0
2020-01-06     0           0
2020-01-07     0           0
2020-01-08     8           100
2020-01-09     11          19
2020-01-10     9           17
```

A visualization of this (ignore the separate linear interpolation over the missing total population) looks like the following:

[image]

I want to smooth this data, but I'm not sure what interpolation method to use. What I want to accomplish is redistribution forwards of the "releases" on date gap(0)-1 and redistribution backwards of "admissions" on date gap(n)+1. For instance, if a gap is 4 days long and on day gap(n)+1 there are 100 admissions, I want to redistribute such that, on each day of the gap, there are 20 admissions, and on day gap(n)+1 admissions are revised to show 20.

Using the above example series, redistribution would look like the following:

```
date(index)    releases    admissions
2020-01-01     15          23
2020-01-02     8           20
2020-01-03     10          14
2020-01-04     10          20
2020-01-05     10          20
2020-01-06     10          20
2020-01-07     10          20
2020-01-08     8           20
2020-01-09     11          19
2020-01-10     9           17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create groups with consecutive zeros + one value before for `releases` and one value after for `admissions`, and then use `transform('mean')` to calculate average for each group:

```
# releases
df['releases'] = df.groupby(
    df['releases'].replace(0, np.nan).notna().cumsum()
)['releases'].transform('mean')

# admissions
df['admissions'] = df.groupby(
    df['admissions'].replace(0, np.nan).notna().iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1]
)['admissions'].transform('mean')
```

Output:

```
            releases  admissions
date                            
2020-01-01        15          23
2020-01-02         8          20
2020-01-03        10          14
2020-01-04        10          20
2020-01-05        10          20
2020-01-06        10          20
2020-01-07        10          20
2020-01-08         8          20
2020-01-09        11          19
2020-01-10         9          17
```

[image: picture]

---

**Update:** For keeping the existing `NA` values:

```
# releases
df['releases_i'] = df.groupby(
    df['releases'].ne(0).cumsum()
)['releases'].transform('mean')

# admissions
df['admissions_i'] = df.groupby(
    df['admissions'].ne(0).iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1]
)['admissions'].transform('mean')
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the 0 --> np.nan replacement? The context is this occurring within group-by groups, and groups may have leading and trailing nulls by date that do not overlap, so I'd need to only redistribute between real values (similar to the pandas interpolate with limit_area='inside').

Comment: @OJT Please see if the version in the `Update` works for you

Comment: Sorry I may have explained poorly -- the new context is trying to get the mean transformation over np.nans, but treating them as zeros in the calculation of the mean (but not converting them to zeros, as then this will operate over legitimate zeros in the data as well).

Comment: I can open this as a new question

Comment: @OJT Sorry I think I'm not quite following yet... maybe it is a good idea if you can open a new question and share some example